# Is there a ui library that renders a calendar using an ical feed from Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I need a Calendar UI for my website that will take in an ical feed from the user's Google Calendar. I know I can use the embed code but the look and feel of the embed Google Calendar is horrible. I am hoping to find a library that has a better UI than the embed Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [UI Calendar using AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) to handle your calendar frontend.

You may also check [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) which is customizable and open source.

If you're not satisfied with any of the libraries/projects available online, you can always start a new one. Hope that helps.